# Как уничтожить элемента массива которые равны null

Tags: java, android

Как уничтожить  элементы массива которые равны `null`?

Вот например:

1. Я создаю массив `String`:
   `String[] aTempVisibleServers = new String[max];`
2. Дальше происходит проверка элементов, тд...
3. И вот я имею массив `aTempVisibleServers` в котором некоторые из элементов не записывались и они имеют значение `null`.

**Пример:**

```
aTempVisibleServers[0]="45"
aTempVisibleServers[1]=null
aTempVisibleServers[2]=null
```

Как мне уничтожить эти `null`?

Просто у меня `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(Массив, индекс и тд)` Видит эти `null` и начинает просто вылетать, заполнить эти `null` не вариант, так как будут видны лишне  пункты в меню.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819635/how-to-remove-all-null-elements-from-a-arraylist-or-string-array

Comment: Спасибо! Нашел, работает!!public static String[] NoNull(final String[] v) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(v));
        list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }` Напишешь ответ отмечу как решение и +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала преобразуем массив `String[]` в `List<String>`, это можно сделать методом `Arrays.asList(T...)`. Однако надо иметь ввиду что данный метод возвращает **не** изменяемую коллекцию, т.е. удалить оттуда элементы не получится. Поэтому создаем новый `ArrayList` в конструктор которого передаем `List` который получили на предыдущем этапе. После чего из только что созданного `ArrayList` можно удалить все интересующие нас элементы методом `removAll(Collection<?> c)`. В качестве параметров к этому методу передается коллекция элементов, которые необходимо удалить.

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что важно понимать: массив в Java имеет неизменяемый размер. Просто выдернуть или вставить элементы в него нельзя. Поэтому нам нужно будет создать новый массив.

Поскольку размер нового массива мы сразу не знаем, то используем вспомогательный список, на основе которого потом будет создан массив.

```
/**
 * Returns a new array containing all non-null values of the filtered array.
 *
 * @param source the array to filter non-null values from
 *
 * */
public static <T> T[] filterNulls(final T[] source) {

    if (source == null ){
        throw new NullPointerException("the filtered array must not be null");
    }

    List<T> list = new LinkedList<>();

    for (T element : source) {
        if (element != null ) list.add(element);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] filtered = (T[]) list.toArray();

    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: Да, вот именно, правда размер нового массива мы сможем узнать если по нем пробежатся и посравнивать по null, но и это не всегда удается

Comment: @ДенисКотляров: можно и так, но это не так очевидно. А еще может так случиться, что после того, как мы посчитаем, в один из прежде пустых элементов будет записано непустое значение (в другом потоке). И тогда второй цикл, который заполняет наш массив, получит `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. А вот этот метод вполне атомарный, его так не сломать.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров: по дженерикам и `@SuppressWarnings ` не возникло вопросов?